# picinpar in list environment

Tags: lists, picinpar

I want to use pininpar package inside a list environment. But as it can be seen from attached files, it doesn't work properly. Any help is appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{picinpar,graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper,textwidth=18cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[t][11cm]{0.47\textwidth}
 \parbox{0.95\textwidth}
  {%
  \begin{figwindow}[0,l,%
    \fbox{\includegraphics[width=30mm]{1046.jpg}},%
                  {This is a runner.}]
   \begin{itemize}
   \item
  a very long long longlong long longlong long long
  a very long long longlong long longlong long long
  a very long long longlong long longlong long long
  a very long long longlong long longlong long long
  item
\item
  a very long long longlong long longlong long long
  a very long long longlong long longlong long long
  a very long long longlong long longlong long long
  a very long long longlong long longlong long long
  item
\item
  a very long long longlong long longlong long long
  a very long long longlong long longlong long long
  a very long long longlong long longlong long long
  a very long long longlong long longlong long long
  item
\end{itemize}
\end{figwindow}
}
  \end{minipage}
}
\hfill
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[t][11cm]{0.47\textwidth}
 \parbox{0.95\textwidth}
  {%
  \begin{figwindow}[0,l,%
    \fbox{\includegraphics[width=30mm]{1046.jpg}},%
                  {This is a runner}]
  a very long long longlong long longlong long long
  a very long long longlong long longlong long long
  a very long long longlong long longlong long long
  a very long long longlong long longlong long long
  item

  a very long long longlong long longlong long long
  a very long long longlong long longlong long long
  a very long long longlong long longlong long long
  a very long long longlong long longlong long long
  item

  a very long long longlong long longlong long long
  a very long long longlong long longlong long long
  a very long long longlong long longlong long long
  a very long long longlong long longlong long long
  item

\end{figwindow}
}
  \end{minipage}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: I want to know the solution of this problem, too. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Doing 'shaped' paragraphs inside lists is particularly tricky in LaTeX. There is a mechanism which should make this much easier available in `xgalley`, but at present we don't have a reimplementation of the various list environments 'ready to go' using this system.

All of that said, the big problem you will have here is that `picinpar` pre-dates LaTeX2e! The documentation is dated 1993-07-13, while the current kernel was released in 1994. As such, 'all bets are off' in terms of behaviour: you get what you get.